# Type Vietnamese in Mathematica

Tags: text, core-language, character-encoding

I type Vietnamese using UTF-8 Encoding but Text Display got error.

How to type Vietnamese, Chinese in Mathematica.

Please help me.

Comment: I would use AutoHotkey.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail?  What exactly did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?  Be sure to also mention your OS, as this is going to be OS-dependent.  I can *type* almost anything, including Chinese, into notebooks, on OS X.